# How to load csv file with specific fields using getsymbols?

Tags: r, csv, quantmod

I have a csv file with fields "Date","Time","O","H","L","C","V"
I want use it with getSymbols function from quantmod package.
The csv file (h1.csv) goes as this:

```
"Date","Time","O","H","L","C","V"
20070801,0001,1.3668,1.3675,1.3666,1.3673,20693
20070801,0100,1.3671,1.3674,1.3652,1.3653,26636
20070801,0200,1.3655,1.3669,1.3651,1.3667,31300
```

R code:

```
library(quantmod)
setSymbolLookup(h1=list(src='csv', format='%Y%m%d')) 
h1 <- getSymbols('h1', dir='C:\\Users\\Admin\\Documents\\R\\csv', auto.assign=FALSE, extension='csv')
barChart(h1)
```

R sends an error: periodicity(x) : can not calculate periodicity of 1 observation

But when I use this R code:

```
library(quantmod)
getSymbols("SPY")
write.zoo(SPY, file="SPY.csv", sep=",")
setSymbolLookup(SPY=list(src="csv",format="%Y-%m-%d"))
spy <- getSymbols("SPY", auto.assign=FALSE)
barChart(spy)
```

anything is ok

Comment: Well, for one thing, your date formats are specified differently.

Comment: R code reads csv file, but columns are wrong
`> library(quantmod)
> setSymbolLookup(h1=list(src='csv', format='%Y%m%d')) 
> getSymbols('h1', dir='C:\\Users\\Admin\\Documents\\R\\csv', auto.assign=FALSE, extension='csv')
     H1.Open H1.High H1.Low H1.Close H1.Volume H1.Adjusted
<NA>       1  1.3668 1.3675   1.3666    1.3673      20693
<NA>       1  1.3671 1.3674   1.3652    1.3653      26636
<NA>       1  1.3655 1.3669   1.3651    1.3667      31300`

Comment: Please define "wrong."  You probably should read the help file for `setSymbolLookup` to find out how to deal with titles, missing values, etc.

Comment: As I read the code for `setSymbolLookup.csv` it is not designed for intraday records. The section of the code that creates the xts index uses `as.Date` rather than `as.POSIXct`, so attempts to pass a two column index with a datetime format have failed in my efforts. I wonder if you need to create an xts file with more basic methods than `setSymbolLookup`

Comment: Thanks DWin! How can I use xts? some example could help. Finally, I want to chart csv data.